# Logging throughout class library without references passes

Tags: c#, .net, logging, class-library

I have a class library in C# and it does lots of different functions for me. I want to be able to log throughout the class, however, I really don't want to have to pass instances of the logging library throughout.

e.g.

```
public void MyMethod(LoggingClass logger)
{
  logger.log("something");
}

public void MyMehtod2(LoggingClass logger)
{
  logger.log("something else");
}
```

I've got classes everywhere throughout this library and am struggling with a good way to do this. I've been looking at dependency injection with Ninject, but can't seem to get my head around how that should work.

So to summarize, I want to be able to have a logging class, and be able to instantiate it once, then use it everywhere to log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a need for a singleton. Simply use a static class in your library:

```
internal static class Logger {

static Logger() {

    // configure logger

}

internal static void Log(string Message, params object[] args) {

    var message = string.Format(Message, args);
    //  write message

}
```

Comment: NOTE: The second parameter in the signature for `Log` has a typo.  The keyword is `params` rather than `param` and the entire line should read: `internal static void Log(string Message, params object[] args) {`

Comment: @IAbstract How would I share a common log between the code that calls the class library and the class library itself?

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be extension methods that implement some static class as mentioned by @IAbstract. If your classes all implement your own ILog interface you could do it something like this:

```
public static void Log(this ILog source, string message)
{
    source.Log(message, null);
}

public static void Log(this ILog source, string message, param object[] args)
{
    // Assuming a static class as mentioned by @IAbstract
    Logger.Log(message, args);
}
```

Then in your classes or from wherever depending on the protection levels you'd be able to use `this.Log(message)` or externally `myClass.Log(message)`. This wouldn't need to be public, but that would be dependent on the needs of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your logger, and call it like `Logger.GetInstance().Log(something)` from wherever you like.

Comment: I think singleton is bad form and not justified in this case.

Comment: I think you may explain that one.

Comment: Singletons should not be a first consideration for any solution. If you first think *"singleton could work here"*, you should simply use a static class. If, however, you determine that the static class does require a state, or must implement some interface, **then** consider a singleton. Most often, static classes will suffice.

Comment: A logger often requires a state, but you're right, a singleton is not the first thing that should come to mind.

Comment: I have yet to write a logger that requires a state. I have used a nested class within the static logger instead - depends on requirements.

Comment: I think your answer could have some validity if you express the benefit of the *singleton* concept: a static class cannot implement an interface whereas a singleton can. Then, with an interface, the object can be interchangeable and unit-testable. Since I wrote the comments above, I have begun using singletons when I want to implement an interface. :)